# Is there a function in AnyLogic to display an alert message during model run?

Tags: anylogic

I would like to display some text in an alert box similar to what the `error()` and `errorInModel()` methods create, but not as an error, just a simple message. I searched for a built-in method in the Help, but couldn't find anything.

It's not intended for an end user, just for myself as an alternative to printing to console during debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, but you can create an agent type with a visual warning msg.

Embed the agent in `Main` as `myAgent`.

When you have your issue, you jump into the agent using `((Main)getRootAgent()).myAgent._origin_VA.navigateTo();`

this will visually jump into the agent.

It is up to you to change the msg in that agent using a text object, obviously.